Test classes are not fed into ArchUnit test case
I fail to implement an ArchUnit test that is meant to prevent test cases getting written that are named with the work "failed" as part of their method name.
For that I use the ImportOption.OnlyIncludeTests.class import option, check for all methods annotation with one of the test case annotations so that I can finally check if the name matches a pattern:
@RunWith(ArchUnitRunner.class)
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.example", importOptions = {
    ImportOption.OnlyIncludeTests.class,
    ImportOption.DoNotIncludePackageInfos.class,
    ImportOption.DoNotIncludeArchives.class
})
public class TestConventionsTest {    
    @ArchTest
    private final ArchRule noTestCaseMethodsWithANameUsingUndesiredWordFailed
        = Conventions.DO_NOT_USE_THE_UNDESIRED_WORD_FAILED_IN_TEST_METHOD_NAMES;
}

The convention is implemented like that:
public class Conventions {
    /**
     * Test methods named with the word "failed" in their names make it harder to spot actually failed
     * tests in the test run output of pipeline runs. Use phrases like "not successful" or "failing" instead.
     */
    public static final ArchRule DO_NOT_USE_THE_UNDESIRED_WORD_FAILED_IN_TEST_METHOD_NAMES =
        noMethods()
            .that().areAnnotatedWith(org.junit.Test.class)
            .or().areAnnotatedWith(org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class)
            .or().areAnnotatedWith(org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest.class)
            .or().areAnnotatedWith(com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchTest.class)
            .should().haveNameMatching("/failed/i");
}

The result at runtime is:

java.lang.AssertionError: Rule 'no methods that are annotated with @Test or are annotated with @Test or are annotated with @ParameterizedTest or are annotated with @ArchTest should have name matching '/failed/i'' failed to check any classes. This means either that no classes have been passed to the rule at all, or that no classes passed to the rule matched the that() clause. To allow rules being evaluated without checking any classes you can either use ArchRule.allowEmptyShould(true) on a single rule or set the configuration property archRule.failOnEmptyShould = false to change the behavior globally.

This looks to me as if no classes are actually fed into the test case. I tried to explude the possibility that no matches are found for the predicates by eliminitating them temporarily, but that does not change anything. I fail to spot anything in my setup that might exclude test classes from getting checked.
My question is: why are no test classes fed into the test, so that no hits are found?

To the person asking to close this question reasoning it "was a typo or unable to reproduce": Sorry, but no, this can be reproduced. Simply by using the code I posted. That is why I posted it.

I cannot reproduce it either: Once there is an @org.junit.Test or @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test or @org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest annotated method in a test within package com.example, I don't get your result. (haveNameMatching("/failed/i") doesn't work as you'd probably expect, but that's another issue.)

@Manfred Hm, strange, then where might be the difference in our setups? I did not make up the error message I posted ...

I wasn't saying that you made it up...  But I agree that we need a minimal reproducible example.

Looks like I got a (partial) solution now, though I am still interested into learning why my first approach did not succeed ...
That seems to work as expected:
@RunWith(ArchUnitRunner.class)
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.example")
public class TestConventionsTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaClasses classes = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("com.example");
        noTestCaseMethodsWithANameUsingUndesiredWordFailed.check(classes);
    }
    
    @ArchTest
    private static final ArchRule noTestCaseMethodsWithANameUsingUndesiredWordFailed
        = Conventions.DO_NOT_USE_THE_UNDESIRED_WORD_FAILED_IN_TEST_METHOD_NAMES;
}

And here the convention:
public static final ArchRule DO_NOT_USE_THE_UNDESIRED_WORD_FAILED_IN_TEST_METHOD_NAMES =
    methods()
        .that().areAnnotatedWith(org.junit.Test.class)
        .or().areAnnotatedWith(org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class)
        .or().areAnnotatedWith(org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest.class)
        .or().areAnnotatedWith(com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchTest.class)
        .should(new ArchCondition<>("not have the undesired word 'failed' in their name") {
            @Override
            public void check(JavaMethod method, ConditionEvents events) {
                if (method.getName().toLowerCase().contains("failed")) {
                    String message = String.format("Method %s in class %s contains 'failed' in its name",
                            method.getName(), method.getOwner().getName());
                    events.add(SimpleConditionEvent.violated(method, message));
                }
            }
        });

